# How logical pixels translate to physical pixels

Tags: flutter

First question:

If I create a Container widget with width set to 50 (logical pixels), how many physical pixels will this widget occupy eventually?
It is correct to assume the answer will be 50*devicePixelRatio and it will be rounded off to an integer value?

Second question:

This question technically arises from the first question. Let say we have 2 devices and each has the same screen width , same resolution but different screen height. In theory, the width value in logical pixels should be the same for both devices right. 
However, one devicePixelRatio will be higher. Hence, the eventual width value in physical pixels will be different and this might cause one of the Container to overflow since my assumption is that the eventual Container widget width will be multiplied by the devicePixelRatio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is correct to assume the answer will be 50*devicePixelRatio and it will be rounded off to an integer value?

Yes

> This question technically arises from the first question. Let say we have 2 devices and each has the same screen width , same resolution but different screen height. In theory, the width value in logical pixels should be the same for both devices right. However, one devicePixelRatio will be higher. Hence, the eventual width value in physical pixels will be different and this might cause one of the Container to overflow since my assumption is that the eventual Container widget width will be multiplied by the devicePixelRatio.

Let's say

`dvp = 1` for first device and `dvp = 2` for second. So a width of `50` in first phone will be

`1 * 50 = 50` device pixels

And for second device it would be

`2 * 50 = 100` device pixels

But **it does NOT mean `Container` `width` is going to be `2x` on second phone and you may run in overflow error**. Not at all!!!

Actually in first phone `50` device pixels are used to create `50` logical pixels box(**less sharpness**) and in second phone `100` device pixels are used to create `50` logical pixels box(**more sharpness**)

Comment: Device pixels here means physical pixels right. As u have mentioned, u are using 50 logical pixels as an example. What if we use the logical pixels value retrieved from MediaQuery.of(context).size.width. Since creating a Container widget using this value will fill the full width of the screen. Would it cause overflow in another device if the device pixel ratio is larger provided that the 2 devices have same screen width , same resolution but different screen height.

Comment: But why?  Let say both device have width of 1080 physical pixels and width of 360 logical pixels since it will be the same for this scenario. Assume the first device density pixel ratio (DPR) is 3 but the second device DPR is 3.5. I imagine If I create a Container with width of 360, first device will fill the full width since 360*3= 1080 physical pixels. But the second device will fill more than the available physical pixels since 360*3.5 = 1260 > 1080 and this will cause overflow error.

Comment: I am sorry this line didn't make any sense to me `Let say both device have width of 1080 physical pixels and width of 360 logical pixels since it will be the same for this scenario.`, do you mean `height` of `1080p`?

Comment: Well to answer your question, `360lp`  `Container` is going to consume `1080dp` in 1st and `1260dp` in second phone for sure, but the `Container` is going to look exactly of same width in both phones, since in 1st phone `3dp` makes `1lp` (less sharpness) and in 2nd phone, `3.5dp` makes `1lp` (more sharpness)

Comment: Do let me know if you have any doubt

Comment: ya but what happens when the second phone only has 1080dp in the direction u talking about (ur 1260dp axis).

Comment: Thanks for follow up. Let me try rephrasing it. First device resolution: 1080dp * x dp, second device resolution: 1080dp * y dp. Assume first device 3.5 DPR and second device 3.0 DPR. Since screen width is the same, assume it will be 360 lp. I create a 360 lp Container, the container width will match the first device screen width ,360*3 = 1080. But for second device, it will be 360*3.5 = 1260 > 1080 overflow??? Does this make any sense, or my understanding is wrong. Correct me if no such scenario might happen.

Comment: Thanks, now I got your question and it's a valid point. Well if you are just using `Container` you can set it `width: 9999` if there is no constraint set from parent, and still there will be no overflow issue. Flutter, takes care of it behind the scene. However, if parent constraints it's width then yes, you are going to see overflow error in 2nd device.